# Need to take list item count on 2010 based on the selected value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, soap, csom

I have a Sample list named as LISTA. In which i have title column, the title column values are

```
Title
  A
  b
  c
  A
  b
  c
  c
```

I need to take the count of item count of a,b,c. using soap services.

Output:

`A=2`
`b=2`
`c=3`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Path to jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>your list name</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://your sharepoint web/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    var liHtml = "";
    var titleArray = {}
    var titles = [];


    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {

        if (typeof titleArray[$(this).attr("ows_Title")] === 'undefined') {
            titleArray[$(this).attr("ows_Title")] = 1;
            titles.push($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
        }
        else {
            titleArray[$(this).attr("ows_Title")]++;
        }


    });

    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        liHtml += "<li>" + titles[i] + "=" + titleArray[titles[i]] + "</li>";
    }
    $("#Results").html(liHtml);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Results">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where **Path to jQuery** is wherever you normally access jQuery from, **your sharepoint web** is the web/site where your list resides, and **your list name** is the name of your list.

Comment: Hi jared Mcgrath, I need to display as below format. can you help me plz.

Comment: Titles A b c
Total 2 2 3

Comment: In table format Title A b c in the first row and Total 2 2 3 in the second row. Please help. thanks in advance..